# Ayuda suma y multiplicacion de numeros php

Tags: php, mysqli, bucle-for

estoy realizado un tienda en php estoy en el tema del carrito ya lo tengo todo realizado casi pero me surje el siguiente problema que aun no he podido resolver

Consultas SQL

```
//solo se muestra los productos de la session del nabegador
mysqli_select_db($conexion, $database_conexion);
$query_DatosUser = sprintf("SELECT * FROM carrito WHERE session=%s",
formatearcadena($_SESSION['carrito'],"text"));
$DatosCarrito= mysqli_query($conexion, $query_DatosUser) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_DatosCarrito = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosCarrito);
$totalRows_DatosCarrito = mysqli_num_rows($DatosCarrito);

$query_DatosProducto = sprintf("SELECT * FROM productos");
$DatosProducto= mysqli_query($conexion, $query_DatosProducto) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_DatosProducto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($DatosProducto);
$totalRows_DatosProducto = mysqli_num_rows($DatosProducto);
```

FUNCIONES

```
$cantidad_prod = $row_DatosCarrito['cantidad']; //retoranaria ej 2 si el producto se agrego 2 veces 
$total_prod = number_format($obj->precio*$cantidad_prod,2); //precio * por cantidad

$subTotal = 0;
for ($i=0; $i <$totalRows_DatosCarrito ; $i++) { 
$subTotal = $subTotal+$obj->precio*$cantidad_prod; 
echo $subTotal."<br>";
}
```

captura:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿ Cual es el valor de la variable $totalRows_DatosCarrito cuando haces el bucle ? Porque tiene pinta de valer 4 lo cual sería un error.

Comment: el valor es de 2 por ej si el carrito de la sesion tiene 2 productos entoces pone 2 si yo aun estoy viedo pero me sale cualquier resultado raro

Comment: Pero si es valor 2 como es que el bucle imprime por pantalla 4 veces.

Comment: aa dale si vi eso poniedo el $i que impria varias veces voy a ver algo aver si sale

Comment: Qué devuelve formatearcadena?